# Node and Require import error in Mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

I have a working Node application and I'm trying to add Mocha tests, but getting some odd import errors.

This is my file structure:

```
package.json
index.js
src/
  chart.js
  highcharts-options.js
test/
  test_chart.js
```

This is what my `chart.js` file looks like:

```
var chartOptions = require('./highcharts-options');
var analyseChart = {
  doSomething: function() { ... }
};
module.exports = analyseChart;
```

And this is what `highcharts-options.js` looks like:

```
var HighCharts = require('highcharts-browserify');
Highcharts.theme = { ... };
```

Currently I import everything from `/src` into a single `index.js` file, then bundle it with `browserify`, which works just fine, no errors in the application.

Now I want to start writing Mocha tests for the functions in `/src`.

This is my first stub in `test_chart.js`:

```
var chart = require('../src/chart');
chart.doSomething();
```

But when I run `mocha`, I get the following error:

```
 Users/.../js/src/highcharts-options.js:11
    Highcharts.theme = {
    ^
    ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../js/src/highcharts-options.js:11:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../js/src/chart.js:7:20)
        at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
        at require (module.js:380:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../js/test/test_chart.js:1:75)
```

How can I fix this import error for Mocha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var HighCharts = require('highcharts-browserify');
Highcharts.theme = { ... };
```

You have a spelling error.
High[cC]harts

**How did you not notice this yourself even when you were told exactly what was wrong?**
Some errors are so common that we ultimately stop trusting them, and start looking for other faults in our code without even investigating it.
This is especially true for the "someVar is undefined" error in javascript.

**Takeaway:**
Sometimes you just got to trust your error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I failed to spot this because I was also getting more complicated import errors after fixing it, so I thought it was connected to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488600/handling-dependencies-not-installed-with-npm-in-mocha