# Handling dependencies not installed with npm, in Mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, require

I have a working Node application and I'm trying to add Mocha tests, but getting some odd import errors.

This is my file structure:

```
package.json
index.js
src/
  chart.js
test/
  test_chart.js
```

This is what my `chart.js` file looks like:

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery');
global.$ = global.jQuery;
require('typeahead');
require('bloodhound');
var bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
var Highcharts = require('highcharts-browserify');
var parse = require('csv-parse');
var moment = require('moment');
var analyseChart = {
  doSomething: function() { ... }
};
module.exports = analyseChart;
```

Currently I import everything from `/src` into a single `index.js` file, then bundle it with `browserify`, which works just fine, no errors in the application.

I have a section in package.json that defines dependencies not available via npm as follows:

```
 "browser": {
   "chosen": "./vendor/chosen.jquery.min.js",
   "typeahead": "./vendor/typeahead.bundle.js",
   "bloodhound": "./vendor/bloodhound.js"
 }
```

Now I want to start writing Mocha tests for the functions in `/src`.

This is my first stub in `test_chart.js`:

```
var chart = require('../src/chart');
chart.doSomething();
```

But when I run `mocha`, I get the following error:

```
 /Users/.../js/node_modules/typeahead/node_modules/dom/lib/matches.js:2
var proto = Element.prototype;
            ^
ReferenceError: Element is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../js/node_modules/typeahead/node_modules/dom/lib/matches.js:2:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../js/node_modules/typeahead/node_modules/dom/index.js:4:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../js/node_modules/typeahead/typeahead.js:3:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../js/src/chart.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../js/test/test_chart.js:3:13)
```

How can I fix this import error for Mocha?

I think maybe it doesn't like `require('typeahead')` because it can't see the `browser` dependency paths that I set in `package.json`.

Is there a way I can make these files available to Mocha as well as browserify?

Or should I use another testing package altogether?

Comment: Is this a Node application or a browser application (or both)? Are you having problems testing the server side code or the client/browser side code? It seems to me it might be client-side code. If so, at you testing in a browser or trying to test in node? Can you showtime unit tests that are failing?

Comment: You should probably be using something like Karma, but that's beyond the scope of the question.